# Construir una pantalla modal responsiva

Tags: css, asp.net, aplicación-web

Tengo un tag div al cual le doy cierto estilo y lo muestro como una pantalla modal, en Pc de escritorio se ve bien, pero en Tablets y telefonos no aparece centrada..Me gustari hacer que fuese responsiva

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi Codigo *(no coloco los botones o etiquetas dentro de la div para hacerlo mas legible , Si es nesesario me dicen y edito mi pregunta)*

```
 <div  align="center" id ='desplegable' style="position: fixed;  width:900px; height: 480px; top: 0px; left:50px; right:0px;
      font-size: 18px; font-weight: normal; border: #333333 3px solid; background-color: #CCCCCC; color: #000000; opacity: 0.8; display:none "> 


  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las reglas CSS para ese contenedor no funcionarán en móviles puesto que has especificado las medidas en píxeles. En este caso, la ventana tiene 900px de ancho y 480px de alto, los móviles y tablets suelen tener una resolución menor.

Para ello, propongo dos alternativas:

- Especificar las medidas de la ventana modal en porcentajes de modo que puedes controlarlo en pantallas de diferentes resoluciones.

Ejemplo en W3Schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

- Usar Bootstrap, librería que te ayudará con la interfaz de tu web. Para este caso tiene un componente llamado "Modal window" que es responsive y realiza lo que tú propones. Además es práctico pues se puede controlar con javascript.

Ejemplo en W3Schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Comment: Gracias Pruebo y te comento....

Comment: De nada. Comenta aquí si tienes novedades.